# Synth levels too low in mixdown (Ableton DNB)

Tags: mixing, ableton-live, levels

I am currently producing a Jump Up Drum and Bass track using ableton, I have gotten to the mixdown and I am concerned as to how loud my synths should be peaking.

I am using Native Instruments Massive to create my synths.

For a reference my kick + snare is currently peaking at -6db.

At the moment my synths are also peaking -6db, I know they should be below the drums but I'm not too sure how much quieter they should be.

It seems if I have them any lower that -7db they are not loud enough, Even with compression and Camel Crusher added.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could do to get my synths peaking around -8db yet still sound loud enough for my track?

Comment: I'd say, use ears not meters. Final track peaks at -0.1dB, everything else is ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to do the wrong thing with them.  Just crushing them may not help at all.

Start with EQing them, Unless they're bass synths you should be shelving the bass quite a bit.

If they are bass, then you should be looking at carving out frequencies for the kick /snare and/or sidechain compressing them.

Tetsujin is correct here.  Listen with your ears as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can double the tracks and lower them altogether, then parallel eq/compress them to make them stick out!